# Connect SIM5360 AWS server GET / POST calls

Tags: json, rest, amazon-web-services

Good afternoon,

I am new to all this and I have a problem that I would like to discuss to see if someone can help me out.

I have a SIM5360 module, with a Vodafone card, and I would like to connect to some web services, to send and receive data in JSON format, which I have implemented on an AWS server.

To execute the AT Commands I use the Putty tool.

I tried to do it first using HTTP functions with the following calls:

```
AT+CHTTPACT=”XX.XXX.XXX.169″, 8080<CR>

+CHTTPACT:REQUEST

GET /XXXDWP/rest/user/list HTTP/1.1<CR><LF>
Host: XX.XXX.XXX.169:8080<CR><LF>
Content-Type: application/json<CR><LF>
Accept: */*<CR><LF>
<CR><LF>
<CR><LF>
<SUB>

<Ctrl + Z>
```

Other examples:

```
GET /XXXDWP/rest/user/list HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: XX.XXX.XXX.169:8080\r\nAccept: */*\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n
GET /XXXDWP/rest/user/list HTTP/1.1 Host: XX.XXX.XXX.169:8080 Accept: */* Content-Type: application/json
```

But the result of my calls is always:

```
+ CHTTPACT: 227
```

I have also tried to do it using TCP functions with the following calls:

```
AT+NETOPEN

AT+CIPOPEN=0,”TCP”,”XX.XXX.XXX.169″,8080

AT+CIPSEND=0,
>GET /XXXDWP/rest/user/list HTTP/1.1<CR><LF>
Host: XX.XXX.XXX.169:8080<CR><LF>
Content-Type: application/json<CR><LF>
Accept: */*<CR><LF>
<CR><LF>
<CR><LF>
<SUB>

<Ctrl + Z>
```

Other examples:

```
>GET /XXXDWP/rest/user/list HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: XX.XXX.XXX.169:8080\r\nAccept: */*\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n
>GET /XXXDWP/rest/user/list HTTP/1.1 Host: XX.XXX.XXX.169:8080 Accept: */* Content-Type: application/json
```

But the result of my calls is always:

```
……..
http/1.1 400 bad request
server: apache-coyote/1.1
transfer-encoding: chunked
……..
```

If someone could give me a hand and give me the steps to follow to correctly configure the SIM5360 and be able to make GET / POST calls to the server.

Thank you very much,

Celia M. S.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence below is taken from the [SIM5360 AT command manual](http://simcom.ee/documents/SIM5360/SIMCOM_SIM5360_ATC_EN_V0.24.pdf), chapter 18.5.

Make sure you have good network by checking it from

```
AT+COPS?
```

Now we're going to use the *Secure Hyper Text Transfer Protocol Service*.
Start by sending

```
AT+CHTTPSSTART
```

wait for `OK`, then send

```
AT+CHTTPSOPSE="<host>",<port>[,<server_type>]
```

and wait for `OK`, then send

```
AT+CHTTPSSEND=<len>[,<filename>]
```

len is the length of request in bytes and filename is the name of the file you want the data to upload from.
After this command you will receive `>`, now send your *GET* request

```
GET /xxxx.xxx
Host: xxx.xxxx.xxx    
User-Agent: curl/x.xx.x    
Content-Length: x
```

Once your request matches the length you specified, SIM5360 will send your data and return

```
OK
+CHTTPS: RECV EVENT
```

indicating that the server responded. 
You can read the response by giving the command:

```
AT+CHTTPSRECV=<len>
```

The Peer can close automatically depending upon the server, but if you want to close it manually then send

```
AT+CHTTPSCLSE
```

and you will receive

```
+CHTTPSNOTIFY: PEER CLOSED
OK
```

At this point, since the Secure HTTP Service is still running, you can send another GET request from `AT+CHTTPSOPSE` command.
But if you want to stop the service, you can send

```
AT+CHTTPSSTOP
```

and SIM5360 will correspondingly respond `OK` on success.

---

I used api.thingspeak.com server for GET request and the server responded as expected by "1". In my case the url for the GET request is api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&field1=xx

Below is copied from my terminal:

```
AT+CHTTPSOPSE="api.thingspeak.com",80,1
OK

AT+CHTTPSSEND=122
>GET /update?api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&field1=xx
Host: api.thingspeak.com
User-Agent: curl/7.45.0
Content-Length: 0    
OK
+CHTTPS: RECV EVENT
+CHTTPSNOTIFY: PEER CLOSED

AT+CHTTPSQECV=512
OK
+CHTTPSRECV: DATA,1
1
+CHTTPSRECV: 0
```

Hope this helps.